# How do I bind command parameter in a context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a UserControl with a number of buttons that run applications on double click.
The button command is bound to the UserControl's ViewModel.LaunchApplicationCommand
The command is passed a parameter which is the viewmodel of the button.

Here's the button command that works:

```
<Button.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ViewModel.LaunchApplicationCommand, ElementName=UserControl}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</Button.InputBindings>
```

What I'm trying to do is run the same command from a context menu on the button. I've tried to bind it to the best of my limited knowledge, but it doesn't work. What's the right way to do this?

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Run" Command="{Binding ViewModel.LaunchApplicationCommand, ElementName=UserControl}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in output window of VS when you debug? Check if `DataContext` is not being set..

Comment: I'll try that and report bank, thanks! I was hoping to not add code, but I know that context menus are a special case.

Comment: That did work, thank you! It's also a handy utility to use in the future.